# expecting end-of-input error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I am new to HAML and i'm having an issue with the code below. I continue to get the error "C:/Users/Dalcom/Desktop/task_tracker/app/views/events/index.html.haml:55: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input".

My view looks like so:

```
#content
  #tab1
  -if @events.exists?
    %table.table.table-hover
      %tr
        %th Name
        %th Priority
        %th Event
        %th Deadline
        %th Event Description
        %th Event Comment
        %th Complete?
  -@events.each do |event|
    %tr
      %td=event.initials
      %td=event.priority
      %td=event.event_name
      %td.deadline=event.deadline.strftime("%m-%d %H:%M")
      %td.description=event.event_description
      %td.comment
        -if event.comment.present?
          =event.comment
          =link_to 'Comments Go Here', edit_event_path(event)
        -else
          =link_to 'Comments Go Here', edit_event_path(event)
      %td
        =form_for event do |f|
          =f.check_box(:complete)
          =f.submit 'Complete?'
  -else
    %p There are no events to be completed!
```

Reading in up on HAML i'm sure it has to do with my indenting but the errors are so horrible I don't knwo where to look.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with my loop that I didn't add a do to. Edited the above code to reflect the working application.